# a mean value theorem question

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

if $f(x)$ can be differentiated to any degree for $x\in (0,+\infty)$ and $f'(x)>0,f''(x)<0$，if $0<a<b$，acordding to mean value theorem we have $\displaystyle\exists \xi\in(a,b),st.\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(\xi)$ ,
prove: $\displaystyle \xi<\frac{a+b}{2}$

And I think that's pretty obvious by looking at the graph of the function,but i don't know how to prove it in math words.

Comment: Sorry. What is $D^{(n)}(0, +\infty)?$

Comment: i modified the problem. sorry, my english is poor...:(

Comment: There is no “graph of the function”, because you are not given a function. You are given properties of a function, and many functions with many graphs will satisfy those conditions.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am pretty sure he/she means heuristically.

Comment: haha ,yes, i tried f(x)=lnx , it's  one of the f(x) satisfy those conditions, intuitively, that's true, and if it's not, I can't find any counterexamples.

Comment: What is obvious looking at a graph of the function?  Please include a graph, and tell us why it's obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not true, here is a counterexample

$$f(x)=\int_0^x(1-e^{-1/t})dt,f'(x)=1-e^{-1/x}>0,f''(x)=\frac{-e^{-1/x}}{x^2}<0,\forall x>0$$

when $a=0.1,b=0.2$, we have $\xi\approx 0.16$

I think in order to get the proposition you want, you need to know something about $f'''$, and information about $f'$ is useless

Comment: +1 Nicely done. A subtle question!

Comment: wow,nice! In fact,i tried to prove if f'>0,f''<0,then f'''>0...and also can't find a counterexample,you also help me sovled this problem by your answer :) thanks .could you tell more details about how do you found this  counterexample..

Comment: the proposition holds when f' is convex, however, a decreasing positive function is not always convex, so I just tried to find a function shaped like →↘→ as f' (sorry, I am using my phone, so i can't give you the image, hope you can understand)

Comment: i got it ! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = \arctan x$, $a={1 \over 8}, b={1 \over 2}$. Since $f''(x) <0$ we see that $f'$ is strictly decreasing, so to provide a counterexample, it is sufficient to show that
${f(b)-f(a) \over b-a} \le f'({a+b \over 2})$ or
${8 \over 3} (\arctan { 1\over 2} - \arctan { 1\over 8}) \le {256 \over 281}$.

Evaluating give $0.904... \le 0.911...$.

Comment: i think the first term  is : pi/2 not pi/4

Comment: @smallsmallice Thanks, I think that invalidates my answer :-(.

Comment: @smallsmallice Thanks for catching that. It is true but much less convincingly so.

Comment: yes,that's right, And compared your anser with  LuOH3's ,i found the  graph of the function"1/(1+x^2)" almost the same as "1-e^(-1/x)" in (0,1),probably,this is the key of the question.